# .Net Core, Identity 4 server in docker environment with TLS

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to create a microservices development environment. I've created a .NET MVC web app that should be authenticated by my other microservice - Identity Server. It works perfectly in an environment without docker but I've been told that dockerized environment is the future - especially for microservices. I'm a newbie when it comes to both Docker as well as microservices so please bear with me.

I've generated self-signed certificates and properly added them to both docker images via DockerFile. One of the Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
COPY ../certs/aspnetapp-root-cert.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5002
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Casino.WebApp/Casino.WebApp.csproj", "Casino.WebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Casino.WebApp/Casino.WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Casino.WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "Casino.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Casino.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Casino.WebApp.dll"]
```

And docker-compose and docker-compose.override look like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqldata:
    container_name: sqldata
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce

  identity-server:
    container_name: identity-server
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identity-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata

  casino-webapp:
    container_name: casino-webapp
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}casino-webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Casino.WebApp/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - bank-service
      - identity-server
volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqldata:
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Super@123Password
      - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
    ports:
      - "5433:1433"
    volumes:
      - casino-sqldata:/var/opt/mssql
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
  identity-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000;http://+:80;https://+:443
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp-identity-server.pfx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=abcdef123
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:443"
    volumes:
      - ./IdentityServer:/root/IdentityServer:cached
      - ./IdentityServer/certs:/https/
      - ./certs/aspnetapp-root-cert.crt:/https-root/aspnetapp-root-cert.crt

  casino-webapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5005;http://+:5004;http://+:80;https://+:443
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5005
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp-casino-webapp.pfx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=abcdef123
    ports:
      - "5004:80"
      - "5005:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Casino.WebApp:/root/Casino.WebApp:cached
      - ./Casino.WebApp/certs:/https/
      - ./certs/aspnetapp-root-cert.crt:/https-root/aspnetapp-root-cert.crt


volumes:
  casino-sqldata:
    external: false
```

In the IdentityServer's Startup I'm changing IssuerUri to identity-server:5001 like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(x => x.IssuerUri = "https://identity-server:5001")
```

And on web app side I'm setting authentication as follows:

```
  
            // http operations
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {                    
                    options.Authority = "https://identity-server:5001";
                    options.ClientId = "casino_mvc_client";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.Scope.Add("address");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("roles");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                    options.Scope.Add("movieAPI");

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {                       
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });
```

The problem I'm facing is that both services are working correctly on proper URIs (https://localhost:500X). But when I try to use web app's pages that need authentication I'm getting an error:

```
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(bool async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

I've spent far too much time on this and I would really appreciate any help to figure this out. This is extremely confusing for me as I think that certificates are working fine (they're generated for DNS=localhost & proper service name).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You said that certificates are generated for localhost but your services URLs are not on localhost, because that's a docker environment. Could it be the issue?

Comment: @AndrewSilver they're generated for localhost with an alternative subject name corresponding it's the service name. https://imgur.com/a/uxVQbCY

Answer (score 0):

assign for all your container the same certificate . for example set for all of the container this pfx =>

```
-ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp-identity-server.pfx  
-ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=abcdef123
```

may this solve your problem